# How to pass data-attribute value to another function outside map function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a slider, what I'm trying to accomplish is to pass the data-attribute from outside my object to the bullet-navigation so that it matches to the current slide? I don't know how I'm stuck.

can someone help?

```
import React from 'react';
import Swiper from 'react-id-swiper';

class RunSwiper extends React.Component {

  render() {

    const dataSlides = [
      'Ga voor grenzeloos',
      'Sectoren',
      'Wat wil jij?',
      'Vlogs',
      'Belangrijke data'
    ];

    const params = {
      pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        clickable: true,
        renderBullet: function (index, className) {
          return '<div class="' + className + '">' + (index + 1) + name + '</div>';
        }
      }
    };

    return (
      <Swiper {...params}>
          {
            dataSlides.map((name, index) => {
                return <div className={`swiper__step swiper__step--${index + 1}`} key={index} data-slide={name}>{name}</div>
            })
          }
      </Swiper>
    )
  }
}

export default runSwiper;
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you mean. what data are you trying to pass where? Are you trying to pass something as a `prop` to your `<Swiper>` component?

Comment: Hi, I am trying to apply the DataSlides object CONTENT text to the RenderBullet so, that the Text will be visible inside the BUllets also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already receiving the `index` as an argument. So you can use that index to access the `name` from the `dataSlides` array.

```
const params = {
   pagination: {
      el: '.swiper-pagination',
      clickable: true,
      renderBullet: function (index, className) {
        return '<div class="' + className + '">' + (index + 1) + dataSlides[index] + '</div>';
      }
   }
};
```